# day not appearing in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, date

I want the date to appear in the bibliography. I am using the `day` property but it is not working.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\cite{test1}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{example}
\end{document}
```

Example.bib contains:

```
@online{test1,
  author = {test},
    institution = {test},
    day = 10,
    month = jun,
    year = 2018,
    title = {{test}},
    note = {\url{test}}
}
```

The output reference is `[tes18] test. test, June 2018. test.` without the day. How can ensure that the day is in the reference ?

Comment: The field `day` is not known to most (all?) BibTeX styles so it will just be ignored. The usual approach is to do something like `"10~" # jun,` if you must absolutely have a day. With `biblatex` you would have to use the `date` field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most BibTeX styles do not know a `day` field, they only know `year` and `month`. If you want to see the day in the bibliography the 'usual' trick is to add the day to the `month` field.

```
month = "10~" # jun,
```

See also item 2 in §2.1 (p. 2) and item 9 in §4 (p. 13) of [BibTeXing (`btxdoc.pdf`)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf).

The disadvantage of this approach is that you need to decide on the date format on input and the date is not formatted by your `.bst` style.

If you use `biblatex` the `day` field is not known either (in fact it is actively deleted, so *it will be ignored*), but you can use the `date` field to input a full date in ISO8601 format

```
date = {2018-06-10},
```

Your style and date settings should then take care of the correct formatting.